# can not understand Curly Curly in tidyeavl in r

Tags: r, tidyeval, non-standard-evaluation

I used `{{}}` to bulid a self-function in r.

I don't understand why this happend.

```
test.data = data.frame(pm10 = 1:5)
test.data

new.col.name = 'lag_pm10'
col = 'pm10'

test.data %>% # error
  mutate({{new.col.name}} := lag({{col}}, 2))

test.data %>% # works
  mutate({{new.col.name}} := lag(get(col), 2))
```

In my view, `new.col.name` and `col` would be parsed when I put them into `{{}}`.

But the situation is that `{{new.col.name}}` works fine and `{{col}}` don't return what I expected.

Then I change `{{col}}` into `get(col)` and it works.

I don't know why.

In my opinion, the two objects' (`new.col.name` and `col`) value are all characters.

It should be the same when I use `{{}}` to `new.col.name` and `col`.

I guess maybe `{{new.col.name}}` become a variable name and `{{col}}` become a parameter in `mutate()`.

If that's the case.
Am I allowed to say that I can use `{{}}`for any variable name and `get()` for all arguments ?

Comment: `{{` is for function arguments. If you have column names in strings, use the `.data` pronoun, see the "Names patterns" section in https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask-programming.html#names-patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this as a function passing unquoted variables and not as a string using the curly-curly `{{` operator like this:

```
my_function <- function(test.data, new.col.name, col) {
  test.data %>% # error
    mutate({{new.col.name}} := lag({{col}}, 2))
}

my_function(test.data, lag_pm10, pm10)
```

Output:

```
  pm10 lag_pm10
1    1       NA
2    2       NA
3    3        1
4    4        2
5    5        3
```